# iOS 4.2 on iPod Touch 2d Gen : is it worth it?

Tags: ipod-touch

Is there any advantage to upgrade the iPod Touch 2d Gen to iOS 4.2 ?

- Is the tech specs enough for that new version ?
- Does it consume more battery ?
- Will it be slower ?

Comment: Upgrade from what? 4.1? 3.x?

Comment: The latest one. I'd say 4.1. Anyway I have done it. And I agreed with Kyle's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say yes. I just upgraded a pair of 2nd gen iPod Touches to iOS 4.2 and it's been really solid so far - it hasn't slowed down the device or impacted the battery as far as I can tell. If you have an Airport Express or new Apple TV the AirPlay feature is very nice - this Thanksgiving I really enjoyed being able to stream music to a pair of speakers directly from the iPod in my pocket. (this *will* affect your battery as the device has to keep WiFi active to stream)

Comment: I thought AirPlay wasn't available on 2nd gen devices?

Comment: @MrMage Worked just fine on mine, but I only tested audio.